# Missing container attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, rancher

I am running EC2 instance with RancherOS ECS-enabled AMI v1.0.4 in ECS cluster.

The instance joins cluster, but ECS tasks are failing to start because container instance is missing an attribute required by the task.

The ECS task that is failing to start has IAM role and requires `com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role` attribute. After checking which attributes the container instance has (using cli aws ecs describe-container-instances), it can be seen that this required attribute is missing.

When I remove IAM role from the task, it starts fine.

When I run instance with Amazon ECS-optimized AMI everything works fine.

I followed [official RancherOS ECS guide](http://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.0/en/amazon-ecs/), including verifying ECS Container Instance IAM Role, without success.

Answer (score 5):

After looking in the source code of ECS agent, it became apparent that by default this functionality is disabled.
In order to enable it environment variable `ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE` should have value `true`.

Adding it to cloud-config file does the job:

```
#cloud-config
rancher:
  environment:
    ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE: true
```